# Do all three bodies cease to exist in Turiya?

Tags: advaita, yoga

Do all three bodies cease to exist/merge with [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) in [Turiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turiya) state? If so, is astral travel or projection no longer possible since the subtle body no longer exists, but merges with Brahman?

Comment: In turiya, there is nothing but brahman, according to advaita. It is a non-dual state. There is no place to travel. Other schools might have different views.

Comment: What about siddhis, such as seeing with third eye? Or does everything ceases to exist except brahman, since everything else is "maya"?

Comment: siddhis are results of practice of yoga of Patanjali. They are lower stages. Turiya is staying sahaja samadhi ie at the highest level : asamprjnata samaadhi which is equivalent to Nirvikalpa Samadhi of vedanta. Ramana Maharshi is believed to remain in the Turiya state most of the time, but He did not perform miracles excepting very few cases

Comment: I was originally turiya from birth (saraswat havyaka Brahmin) but I was food poisoned(maybe pitru dosha), which sealed my soul. In turiya state, if I know correctly soma is being produced every single second by heaven in our brain, then distributed throughout body via Chakras, nadis, so is it not possible to astral travel when soma is produced in our brain?

Comment: In advaitic term somebody goes to turiya state and came back means he is still not self realized, the self realized should already be dead because he is already bhraman and worship such advaitic brahman is idotic because there is only one brahman, than brahman should be worshiped instead of person who is still identified.. with ahamkara..

Comment: If all three bodies cease to exist, merge with brahman, there's nowhere to travel, then how was shankaracharya (probably shankaracharya was turiya/jivanmukta from birth, like most of pure saraswat Brahmins are) was able to parakaya pravesha? Did he specifically temporarily created three bodies for purposes of parakaya pravesha?

Comment: What about doing yoga or sadhana in turiya? Are any siddhis attainable/ or attained automatically by default in turiya?

Comment: Turya is a higher-level state when you discover infinite yourself and you are able to differentiate Maya properly and totally stay away from it. In Parakaya Pravesha - you need to stay in Maya (Astral space) and have an out-of-body experience. You can have an out-of-body experience in a dream state (Nidra Yoga Tantra) and that is inferior to turya (according to Mandukya Upanishad. Is that what you mean??

Coming out of the body is NOT liberation. Liberation is coming out of the world into the brahman which is unchanging.

Comment: I agree the sheath is not a sheath.  the kosha is not a sheath.  it's more like an energy field with so-called waves at the edges....but the waves are belonging to one ocean